I was a driver before I become/became a salesman?
What's the right to use with the second verb in the case when I speak about to actions that already happened in the past?
Please answer this question, providing the rule, if there is any; and the following questions too.
Example 1:
(A) I used to be a translator before I (become) a teacher.
(B) I used to be a translator before I (became) a teacher.
Example 2:
(A) I used to be busy before I (join) this place.
(B) I used to be busy before I (joined) this place.
Example 3:
(A) He told me that right before he (leaves).
(B) He told me that right before he (left).
I think what I usually hear from native speakers is answer B; but isn't A logical as well, since the action happened in the past too?
For example in question 1: I was a translator (past), and I already became a teacher a long time ago (also past).

As both actions are in the past, of course both verbs are in the past tense.

Could be a translation issue similar to false friends. We all assume our language system applies to the next, when they don't. You may know that in Spanish, they say "I have two meters tall, I have 21," but English uses "am." In Hebrew, "Give hand," but English uses "Give me your hand."

This might seem strange yet can you say how Example 3 came into this? It seems clear that was included because to you, Ex 3 has a significant relationship to Ex 1 & 2.
To me, the interesting part of the Question is how you came to consider Ex 3 as comparable, unless that was only for their differences - which seems highly explain…

As you became a salesman in the past, that verb should also be in the past tense. This is just natural tense, there is no special use of tense. (A) would be incorrect (and illogical).  (A) uses present tense which isn't used for actions in the past.
Use "became".

Additionally, "before I join" refers to a habitual action or a future action (of joining). OP's examples do not refer to habitual actions, so they would need to match tenses by saying something like "I will be a translator before I become a teacher".
